# Abosulte path for local file

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a local HTML page generated for print purposes, It references some local images. All of them at same folder alongside the page.

My problem resides on how to reference those images I try this:

```
<img alt="name" src="c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\MyAppFloder\logo.png"/>
```

And this:

```
<img alt="name" src="file://C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/MyAppFloder/logo.png"/>
```

This Works on Firefox but not in IE, and In my app I'm using IE (10/11) activex to render de page before printing it.

What is the propper way to reference those images in IE 10,11 on win8, win7  ?

Comment: `<img src="file:///C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/myappfolder/logo.jpg" />` works on FF, GC and IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in IE11:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="c://Users/username/Desktop/x.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference to your images with the absolute URL. E.g.:

```
<img alt="name" src="http://yourDomain.com/public/img/logo.png" />
```

or with relative path. E.g.:

```
<img alt="name" src="../public/img/logo.png"/>
```

or

```
<img alt="name" src="public/img/logo.png"/>
```

Comment: I believe he means absolute referencing for local files, not domain hosted ones.

Comment: Yes tks, but my page is a local page, not in a domain

Comment: Tks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

To find an absolute path for any file/folder not just image, you hold down shift and right click and then click on copy as path, that works both on ie and ff on win 7. I've just tested it. Then you can just paste it into the browser and check by removing the quotes.

Make sure you hold shift and right click otherwise the 'copy as path option' isnt there.
more info here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678296.aspx